# Special handling for first element in observable

Tags: c#, observable, reactive

This seems like it should be trivial but I have wasted hours on it.  I have an Observable of strings:

```
S:  ---a------b----------c------->
```

and I want to transform it somehow into comma separated strings:

```
L:  ---a------,b---------,c------>
```

Note that there is no comma before the first item; this is critical.  I could then subscribe to this sequence to output a comma separated list:

```
L.Subscribe(Console.Write); // "a,b,c,..."
```

(BTW: S is slow).

An obvious solution involves creating a sequence of separators:

```
C:  -- --,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,-->
```

Then we just zip them:

```
L = S.Zip(C, (s,c)=>c+s)
```

It's easy to create C, right?  `C = Observable.Return("").Concat(Observable.Repeat(",")).`

But I see two problems with infinite sequence solutions like Repeat:

1. The call to L.Subscribe() *blocks*.  I really don't want it to block.
2. It feels really inefficient.  While we're waiting on S, C is pumping out values like crazy - 99% of which we throw away.  I tried replacing Repeat with Interval(TimeSpan.Zero) and got 100% CPU!

Solving these infinite sequence problems would be great, but I guess it would also be okay to find a general way to have special handling for that first element.  Whatever the solution, the current implementation of S must not be touched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could skip applying `,` to the first element by using `.Select()` overload which exposes the index of the current element.

Something like:

```
using System;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace RxTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var observable = "abcd".ToObservable()
                .Select((c, i) => i == 0 ? c.ToString() : $",{c}");

            observable.Subscribe(Console.Write); 
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
a,b,c,d
```

Hope that helps.